# Is mongodb deleteMany() atomic?

Tags: mongodb

Is `db.collection.deleteMany()` under mongodb atomic (in this page: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.deleteMany/#mongodb-method-db.collection.deleteMany)? Meaning either delete none (if failure) or delete all but not delete partial (if failure)?

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/delete/#transactions…?

Comment: See MongoDB doc on [Atomicity and Transactions](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/).